# Retain array structure when filtering nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

My brain froze with this advanced filtering. This task has exceeded my basic knowledge of `filter`, `map` etc.

Here I have an array with nested objects with array:

```js
const DATA = [
    {
        title: 'Spongebob',
        data: [
            { id: 1, name: 'Mr Crabs' },
            { id: 2, name: 'Sandy' }
        ]
    },
    {
        title: 'Dragon Balls Z',
        data: [
            { id: 1, name: 'GoKu' },
            { id: 2, name: 'Zamasu' }
        ]
    }
];
```

You may have seen this sort of style if you've worked with [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist) (RN). This question is not for RN. I need to perform a filter on the `name` property in the nested array and when I get a match, I must return the format as the `DATA` variable.

```js
const handleFiltering = (value) => {

    const _value = value.toLowerCase();

    const results = DATA.map(o => {
        return o.data.filter(o => o.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(_value) != -1)
    });

    console.log(results);
};
```

My limited knowledge of deep filtering returns the basic filtering for the `data` array but need to retain the structure for `DATA`. The expected results I'd expect:

```js
// I'm now querying for "ZAMASU"

const handleFiltering = (value='ZAMA') => {

    const _value = value.toLowerCase();

    const results = DATA.map(o => {
        return o.data.filter(o => o.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(_value) != -1)
    });

    // console.log(results) should now be
    // [
    //  {
    //      title: 'Dragon Balls Z',
    //     data: [
    //          { id: 2, name: 'Zamasu' }
    //      ]
    //  }
    // ];
};
```

What comes to mind is the use of `{...DATA, something-here }` but my brain has frozen as I need to get back the title property. How to achieve this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution would be first use filter to find only objects containing the name in data passed through the argument, subsequently mapping data.

Here is your adjusted filter method

```
const handleFiltering = (value) => {
  const _value = value.toLowerCase();

  const results = DATA.filter((obj) =>
    obj.data.some((character) => character.name.toLowerCase() === _value)
  ).map((obj) => ({
    title: obj.title,
    data: obj.data.filter(
      (character) => character.name.toLowerCase() === _value
    ),
  }));

  console.log(results);
};
```

Comment: it would be better the other way round: do map+filter first and then filter by `data.length > 0`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` method of array. First find out the object inside data array and then add that to accumulator array as new entry by preserving the original structure.

```js
const DATA = [
    {
        title: 'Spongebob',
        data: [
            { id: 1, name: 'Mr Crabs', where: 'tv' },
            { id: 2, name: 'Sandy' }
        ]
    },
    {
        title: 'Dragon Balls Z',
        data: [
            { id: 1, name: 'GoKu' },
            { id: 2, name: 'Zamasu' }
        ]
    }
];


let handleFiltering = (value='tv') => {
 return DATA.reduce((acc,d) => {
           let obj = d.data.find(a => a.name?.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()) 
|| a.where?.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()));
           obj ? acc.push({...d, data:[obj]}) : null; 
           return acc;
    }, []);
}

let result = handleFiltering();

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hey Radjdeep. Thanks. I have one slight question to ask. What if, in the `data` array I have `{id: 1, name: 'GoKu', where: 'tv'}, {id: 2, name: 'Zamasu', where: 'tv'}` and I query for "tv", how to get both objects? The `find` method is giving some mixed results.

Comment: In the find method you want `name==='Zama' OR where==='tv'`? Something like this? I mean with which to match where?

Comment: Yes but the `find` is returning only one object.

Comment: Radjeep, I'll have to go with Prebiusta's answer as it's scalable. I've upvoted your answer though as it's useful in other parts of my code. That's for taking the time to supply an answer.

Comment: That's ok, select the best one as per your requirement